# Google Cloud - Virtual machine down (RDP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2016

I have a VM on google cloud and I have been using it for few years. Every now and then, I suddenly won't be able to connect anymore via RDP. It simply says that the IP is unreachable, like when a server is down or doesn't exist.

Another thing is that the server also restarts by itself (seems like a failure, which is something I would expect from windows).

For the outage scenario, what I would normally do is access the dashboard (cloud.google.com) > virtual machines > stop and start the VM, but the issue with that is because the IP gets changed to a new one. This is the frustrating bit because I have applications pointing to this IP and other people using this IP to connect via RDP as well.

Any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: [Reserve a static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address), then start looking at logs to figure out *why* it's crashing.

Comment: Windows Server seldom "crashes" as you put it. It is far more likely that updates were installed or Google performed maintenance on the cluster.

Comment: You could use a ddns service (who's pointing directly to ip's today anyway?). Also check you logs, a windows 10 desktop is under power user load wayyyy more reliable than macos or a ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to Reserve a static external IP address, there are two types of external IP addresses:

A regional IP address which can be used by [VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances) with one or more network interfaces or by [Network load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network).

A global IP address which can be used for global load balancers: [HTTP(S)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https), [SSL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl), and TCP proxy.

Reserve a static external IP address in the **gcloud** command-line tool or through the API. After reserving the address, assign it to an instance during instance creation or to an existing instance.

In this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) they explain how to reserve and apply it to your instance.